# Hibernate Query for equivalent sql

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql

Can someone help me in writing equivalent hql for this query

```
SELECT IFNULL(oea.`organization_name`,'') FROM `consultation_appointment` ca 
JOIN `organization_employee_association` oea ON ca.`consultation_id` = oea.id
JOIN professional_profile pp ON oea.`employee_profile_id` = pp.profile_id
```

I could able to join the first JOIN like this

```
select ca.name from ConsultationAppointment ca join ca.consultation oea
```

Because the ConsultationAppointment class having organization_employee_association variable so it easier to join, difficulty is organization_employee_association not having direct mapping to organization_employee_association class.

Even GORM criteria Query is helpful.

Comment: Well, add this association...

Comment: @JB Nizet if you don't mind can you make it much more clear

Comment: You're aware that you need an association between entities in order to create a join between those entities. So add the necessary association. I can't be more precise without knowing any of your entities and tables.

Comment: Yes, risen because of design issue

Answer (score 1):

HQL does not allow joining two unassociated entity, you should use cartesian product  instead.

```
String query = "SELECT ca.name FROM consultation_appointment ca JOIN organization_employee_association oea, professional_profile pp WHERE oea.employee_profile_id = pp.profile_id";
List<String> caNames = session.createQuery(query).list();
```

One another possibility is to use the method `createSQLQuery()`. It provides more flexibility to execute an arbitrary join.

```
String query = "SELECT ca.name FROM consultation_appointment ca JOIN organization_employee_association oea ON ca.consultation_id = oea.id JOIN professional_profile pp ON oea.employee_profile_id = pp.profile_id";
List<String> caNames = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
```

Comment: but only if there is no possibility we can try this. But there should be some ways in hql we have to dig that

Comment: thanks for your effort, but there is error, also we already tried like this, error is on using "on" clause in the query